# Correct way to set default prop to the first item in prop array

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I have this wrapper around ag-Grid that takes in a array of `Definition` as prop. I'm trying to set the `className` field in `Def` for the first item `IDummyComponentProps`. I can achieve it as shown below, by doing `props.Definition[0].className = "clickableCell"` but is this the right way to go about it?

```
interface IDummyComponentProps {
    Definition: Def[];
}

interface Def {
    fieldName: string;
    className?: string;
}

const DummyComponent: React.FC<IDummyComponentProps> = (props) => {
    props.Definition[0].className = "clickableCell";

    return (
        <div
            className="ag-theme-material"
            style={{
                height: props.Height,
                width: props.Width,
            }}
        >
            <AgGridReact
                columnDefs={props.Definition}
                rowData={someRowData}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. You are modifying props and hence breaking the core ReactJS requirement of keeping props as read-only. As the official docs state:

> Whether you declare a component as a function or a class, it must
>   never modify its own props.

https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only

Instead you should make a copy of props using `{...}` spread operator or `Object.create` and make changes to the copy.

Answer (score 0):

Note: You cannot modify component own props inside this component.

If you want to have a default props, you can do this way,

```
const DummyComponent: React.FC<IDummyComponentProps> = (props) => {
    // Your component code
    // ...
}

DummyComponent.defaultProps = {
    Definition: [
        { className: "clickableCell" }
    ]
}
```

Hope this help.